# I'm seeking for better performance query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm seeking for a better solutions for this problem

1. Here is the dataset: https://8weeksqlchallenge.com/case-study-1/
2. In the question 9, which is:
   "If each $1 spent equates to 10 points and sushi has a 2x points multiplier - how many points would each customer have?"
3. In this question, I assume that customers are only received points after became member. After that, here is my query:

```
WITH CTE as -- Create CTE that includes customer_id, product_name, and Total Point broken by customer and product.
      (SELECT 
          s.customer_id customer, 
          m.product_name,
          count(s.product_id)*m.price*CAST(
                      CASE
                          WHEN m.product_name = 'sushi'
                              THEN 10*2
                          ELSE 10
                      END as int) Total_Point
      FROM sales s
      Join menu m
      ON s.product_id = m.product_id
      Join members mem
      On mem.customer_id = s.customer_id
      WHERE s.order_date >= mem.join_date
      GROUP BY s.customer_id, m.product_name, m.price
      ) 
  SELECT customer, sum(Total_Point) Total_Point
  FROM CTE
  GROUP BY customer
```

Actually I got the right things that answered the question, but I think it could be better and more optimized.

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a5bd4c297edc518f0bb333e2bea51297)

Table definitions are:

```
CREATE TABLE sales (
  "customer_id" VARCHAR(1),
  "order_date" DATE,
  "product_id" INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO sales
  ("customer_id", "order_date", "product_id")
VALUES
  ('A', '2021-01-01', '1'),
  ('A', '2021-01-01', '2'),
  ('A', '2021-01-07', '2'),
  ('A', '2021-01-10', '3'),
  ('A', '2021-01-11', '3'),
  ('A', '2021-01-11', '3'),
  ('B', '2021-01-01', '2'),
  ('B', '2021-01-02', '2'),
  ('B', '2021-01-04', '1'),
  ('B', '2021-01-11', '1'),
  ('B', '2021-01-16', '3'),
  ('B', '2021-02-01', '3'),
  ('C', '2021-01-01', '3'),
  ('C', '2021-01-01', '3'),
  ('C', '2021-01-07', '3');
 

CREATE TABLE menu (
  "product_id" INTEGER,
  "product_name" VARCHAR(5),
  "price" INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO menu
  ("product_id", "product_name", "price")
VALUES
  ('1', 'sushi', '10'),
  ('2', 'curry', '15'),
  ('3', 'ramen', '12');
  

CREATE TABLE members (
  "customer_id" VARCHAR(1),
  "join_date" DATE
);

INSERT INTO members
  ("customer_id", "join_date")
VALUES
  ('A', '2021-01-07'),
  ('B', '2021-01-09');
```

Comment: What's the table schema? Indexes? What's the execution plan? If the query is trying to filter or join on fields that aren't indexes, it will have to scan all rows in a table. The same query can run thousands of times faster with or without indexes

Comment: Off site links to a database aren't helpful. If you want to include the details of the database in your question, do so by putting the DDL and DML statements in your question.

Comment: You can't expect us to read a whole article. Help us to help you. Simplify.

Comment: And although many, including myself (when i can) use fiddles, it's to compliment an answer, @Charlieface . I don't post an answer and say "you can use `ROW_NUMBER`, here's a [db<>fiddle]" and don't post the solution in the answer itself. The same is true for questions. The Fiddle should compliment the question, but not be required.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. I'm completely a newbie here, I don't even know what are index and fiddledb. Thank you for all of your comments guys, that help me alot for finding out what I need to learn. Especially, I do appreciate your kind support, Charlie! @Charlieface

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this query by removing the CTE, and just summing up by `customer`

```sql
SELECT 
  s.customer_id customer, 
  Total_Point = SUM(m.price * CASE WHEN m.product_name = 'sushi' THEN 20 ELSE 10 END)
FROM sales s
JOIN menu m ON s.product_id = m.product_id
JOIN members mem On mem.customer_id = s.customer_id
  AND s.order_date >= mem.join_date
GROUP BY
  s.customer_id;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ea75e88a73bb6f9fecb9a61a6e48e423)

I would recommend indexing as follows

```
sales (customer_id, order_date)

members (customer_id, join_date)

menu (product_id) INCLUDE (price, product_name)
```